# TypeError: ... is not a function

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm trying to test my contract functions in Truffle v5+ but getting `TypeError: myContract.methods.register is not a function`.

```
Contract MyContract {
    function register(uint256 amount) external {...}
}
```

In my Truffle migration file:

```
const MyContract = artifacts.require("MyContract");

module.exports = async function(deployer) {
    deployer.logger.log("Deploying MyContract");
    await deployer.deploy(MyContract, someConstructorParam);
}
```

In my Truffle test file:

```
contract("MyContract", accounts => {
  let myContract;

  before(async () => {
    myContract = await MyContract.deployed();
  });

  it("can register", async () => {
     await myContract.methods.register(1000).send({ from: accounts[1] }); // <<<< This is where the error is thrown.
     ...
  });
}
```

When I `console.log(myContract.methods)`, included in the methods is:

```
'register(uint256)': [Function] {
   call: [Function],
   sendTransaction: [Function],
   estimateGas: [Function],
   request: [Function]
}
```

And when I change it to `await myContract.register(1000, { from: accounts[1] });` I get `Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first error is because the Truffle contract object is somewhat different from the Web3 contract object (the `methods` field is viable only in the latter).

Comment: The second error is because of something that you do inside the `register` function (mostly likely a falsified `require` statement).

Comment: Thanks @goodvibration. So the invocation itself that results in the second error is correct, which is the problem I'm asking about. Now, my next challenge is fixing the falsified `require` inside `register`. You are on point, yet again. Thanks man!

Comment: Well, since you have not provided the code of function `register`, my notion about the falsified `require` statement is only an educated guess. The revert could also be the result of a bunch of other reasons. No one can tell without seeing your actual code.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I did identify the falsified `require` statement as the issue by sticking a `return;` just above it, which calls the function without error.

Comment: You know you can just add an error-message in the `require` statement, then you'll see it printed in the console, right?

Comment: @goodvibration Using Truffle v5+ and ganache-cli, I only get `Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`, but no revert reason, even with an error message in each of the function's `require` statements.

Comment: So perhaps it is not that specific `require` statement which is causing the revert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to test my contract functions in Truffle v5+ but getting `TypeError: myContract.methods.register is not a function`.

Truffle's logical contract object, which can be generated by either one of the following:

- `artifacts.require("...").new(<construction arguments>)`
- `artifacts.require("...").at(<deployment address>)`
- `artifacts.require("...").deployed()`

Is somewhat different from Web3's logical contract object.

In particularly starting from Web3 v1, where all contract functions are accessible via the `methods` field of the contract object, while in Truffle they are accessible directly via the contract object.

Comment: Thanks. I `ganache-cli --fork`ed Kovan to let my contract interact with already-deployed contracts, so I didn't know I was dealing with Truffle contracts _and_ Web3 objects.

Answer (score 0):

For upgradeable contracts, make sure

- you are calling the upgraded contract
- your contracts have something like this `__ERC20Burnable_init_unchained();` in their `initialize` functions