# Sending transaction to a Web3 contract object in Truffle test produces 'file import callback not supported'

Tags: web3js, truffle, openzeppelin

I need to send a state-changing transaction to a Web3 contract object in my Truffle tests, which is hitting a fork of Kovan in my local ganache chain (`ganache-cli --fork https://kovan.infura.io/v3/[api_key]@latest`).

The contract I'm sending a transaction to is a Web3 contract object of an already-deployed contract on Kovan.

```
const theirContractABI = require("./abi/TheirContract");
const theirContractAddress = "0x123456789...";
const theirContract = new web3.eth.Contract(theirContractABI, theirContractAddress);

contract("MyContract", accounts => {
   it("can update a TheirContract property", async () => {
      await theirContract.methods.someFunction().send({ from: accounts[0] });
      ...
      assert(some condition);
   });
}
```

When I run this specific test, all I get is `Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`, and it's not produced by a falsified `require` statement. So, I tried using `@0x/sol-trace`. When I run `yarn trace`, I get

```
error InitializableAdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol:3:1: ParserError: Source "/Users/slider/Desktop/myProject/node_modules/@openzeppelin/upgrades/contracts/upgradeability/BaseAdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

import './BaseAdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol';    
^------------------------------------------^
```

and

```
error InitializableAdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source "/Users/slider/Desktop/myProject/node_modules/@openzeppelin/upgrades/contracts/upgradeability/InitializableUpgradeabilityProxy.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

import './InitializableUpgradeabilityProxy.sol';    
^------------------------------------------^
```

`TheirContract` imports `@openzeppelin/upgrades/contracts/upgradeability/InitializableAdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol`, but I have the `@openzeppelin/upgrades` package installed, and `BaseAdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol` & `InitializableUpgradeabilityProxy.sol` are indeed located in the same file within `node_modules` as `InitializableAdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol`.

[image]

So, I'm fairly unsure of where the issue stems from and how to resolve it. Would greatly appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: As I've already explained in an answer to [a previous question of yours](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83897/16043), Truffle's logical contract object is different from Web3's logical contract object. So you should avoid using the latter within your Truffle tests.

Comment: I'm able to use the Web3 contract method with an ERC20 contract and change an address balance in my Truffle tests. Is there a recommended way of Truffle-izing an already-deployed contract, or do I need to copy+paste the contract and all of its dependencies into their own files?

Comment: Also, I'm still curious as to the underlying issue, whether it's related to sending a transaction to a Web3 contract object or not...

Comment: Truffle-izing an already-deployed contract: `const myContract = artifacts.require("MyContract").at(myContractAddress);`.

Comment: I'm trying to Truffle-ize someone else's contract, say MakerDAO. I could get its state by forking mainnet or Kovan in ganache-cli, but how would I reference it in my tests? Grab the contract code and copy+paste into its own file? There has to be a better way.

Comment: Add [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/contract) to your installation and use it in your Truffle tests.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @goodvibration. Fortunately, the issue was related to the `gasLimit` in my `send()` method. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, all I had to do was specify a `gasLimit` in my `send()` method!

From this:

`await theirContract.methods.someFunction().send({ from: accounts[0] });`

To this:

`await theirContract.methods.someFunction().send({ from: accounts[0], gasLimit: 800000 });`

And I can use the Web3 contract object to do so, which is the easiest way to reference an already-deployed contract that I'm currently aware of, because you can just grab the ABI and address from EtherScan, and fork mainnet/Kovan/etc to your local ganache chain!